# Center div with overflow left and right

Tags: html, css

This looks like a very simple problem but I can't find the answer:

I want to center a div with fixed width of 500px.
Markup and styling is as follows:

```
<div>
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, diceret delectus ea quo, ne eum essent legendos tacimates. Vel at perfecto omittantur. Iusto dolores sed an, error copiosae at his. Laoreet veritus vocibus te mel. An eos assum nobis vituperata, pro ad labitur facilis.
</div>

body {text-align:center;}
div {display:inline-block;width:500px;}
```

This works well when the viewport is wider than my div. However when the viewport gets smaller than my div, it is no longer centered but overflows to the right. I want my div to overflow on both sides of the viewport so it stays centered. Is this possible with CSS?

```css
body {text-align:center;}
div {display:inline-block;width:500px;}
```

```html
<div>
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, diceret delectus ea quo, ne eum essent legendos tacimates. Vel at perfecto omittantur. Iusto dolores sed an, error copiosae at his. Laoreet veritus vocibus te mel. An eos assum nobis vituperata, pro ad labitur facilis.
</div>
```

Comment: `left: 50%;` `margin-left: -250px; /* Half of width */` take a look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3157372/css-horizontal-centering-of-a-fixed-div)

Comment: Like this https://jsfiddle.net/j08691/52n765ob/?

Comment: Thanks, it must overflow to both left and right, no other way than position:fixed though? Just curious.

Comment: @Xorifelse anyway your comment DID solve my problem, can i accept comments as an answer? :)

Comment: You can upvote comments ;) That trick is so widely known I cannot take credit for it.

Answer (score 0):

First off why would someone ever zoom in that far to that. Now I think you would have to do something like `overflow: hidden;` into the css and that should work. This question could already be answered at [is this the answer you're looking for?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9709125/how-do-i-stop-a-css-layout-from-distorting-when-zooming-in-out)

Answer (score 0):

Here you go

[Working JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/0k94s6wL/)

```
@media (max-width: 500px) {
  div {
      width:auto;
  }

}
```

It will still be 500px wide, but when enter a smaller screen, in this example 500px wide, it will get the width:auto property, and allow the text to stay centerered and stay on the screen.

You can read more about media queries [here](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_mediaquery.asp)

Hope this helped you out :)

// Marc Hjorth

Comment: Thanks but the div must overflow on both sides, not wrap, Xorifelse comment is best so far.

Comment: Okay I'm sorry then, I don't think I understand what you intend to do.