# How to make two elements intact on zoom level change?

Tags: css, html, alignment, zooming

I have a simple tag with a banner and a border at the bottom. How can I stop sliding these two elements on zooming? I was looking for a way to get the two elements intact on zoom in and out. Even after a few hours of search, i couldn't get the desired output. I tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9709125/how-do-i-stop-a-css-layout-from-distorting-when-zooming-in-out) and one more post which says to change from px to em.

My html tag:

```
<head>    
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style/style.css" />  
</head>
<body> 
    <div id="header">            
      <img class="logo" src="./style/logo.jpg" width= 895 height= 160">         
    </div>
  <div id="container-border">           
  </div>
</body>
```

css:

```
 #header
{ padding:0 20px;
  display:block;
  margin:0 auto;
  background: #D6D6D6 url(background.jpg) repeat-x;
  height: 205px;
  width: 1500px;
  position: center;
}


  #container-border {  
  width: 1538px;
  height:900px;
  margin-left:260px;
  border-color: black;
  border-width: 1px;
  border-style: solid;  
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You first need to wrap the content in a containing DIV

**HTML**

```
  <div class="site-content">
      <div id="header">            
        <img class="logo" src="./style/logo.jpg" width= 895 height="160">         
      </div>
    <div id="container-border">           
    </div>
  </div>
```

Note the new `DIV` `.site-content`. This is where you would center the website content and control the website contents width.

Here's my codepen: https://codepen.io/arlcode/pen/aRpWZo

I would also recommend not using static width/height for mobile dynamic purpose. You're also going to want to use classes more then ID's because ID's are specific but classes allow you to manipulate multiple DIVs at once.

Comment: I was looking for 'site-content'. I'm trying to make a simple web based biological database. Thank you for the help.!@ARLCode

Comment: Not a problem, bud. Let me know if you need anything else! Good luck out there!